# how to monitor up time and down time of a linux service

Tags: linux, monitoring, services

How to monitor up time and down time of a linux service.

I have created a service for my application using chkconfig (RHEL 6.3).
I want monitor when the service is turned started and stopped.

I can monitor the service by writing to log file while giving `service test start/stop` but this wouldn't catch my application if it crashed or abnormally terminated.

Comment: What kind of monitor do you want? One that writes a log to let you track at which time the service died, if it died. Or something more advanced which actually notifies you in multiple ways if something is wrong?

Comment: on systemd, the init system will keep track of this for you. this doesn't apply to you since IIRC RHEL isn't systemd-based but for future visitors it may be (and I don't know enough to write a full answer).

Comment: What types of notification are you looking for if the service goes down? are you interested in just the up/down times being logged to a file or do you want an email sent when this occurs?

Comment: @mauro.stettler  I want a simple monitor just to log when died. very very simple one (just monitor a single service always).

Comment: @slm . I am interested in log file only but mail notification will also be good (if possible and if it is simple solution without any tools).

Comment: What does this service *do*?  Better than monitoring for the process would be to make sure that the service *behaves* as you expect.  If it's a web server, make a web request.  If it's an SMTP server, do some basic SMTP commands to make sure it's functional.  Describe your service.

Comment: @ghoti . My application is Jboss Web server.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to monitor  many application on different server then Go for NagiOS, if you want to monitor specific application,file ownership,anything then Go for Monit.

[**You can use Monit**](http://mmonit.com/monit/)

To monitor daemon processes or similar programs running on localhost. Monit is particular useful for monitoring daemon processes, such as those started at system boot time from /etc/init.d/. For instance sendmail, sshd, apache and mysql.

In difference to many monitoring systems, Monit can act if an error situation should occur, e.g.; if sendmail is not running, Monit can start sendmail again automatically or if apache is using too much resources (e.g. if a DoS attack is in progress) Monit can stop or restart apache and send you an alert message. Monit can also monitor process characteristics, such as; how much memory or cpu cycles a process is using

**Update ::  Configuration Part**

Monit is easiest to install through aptitude or apt-get

```
sudo aptitude install monit
```

Once monit downloads, you can add programs and processes to the configuration file

```
vim /etc/monit/monitrc

set daemon 3                    # check services at 3-second intervals
set logfile /var/log/monit.log  # you can see what monit is doing
set alert sysadm@foo.bar        # receive all alerts
include /etc/monit.d/*          # add monit script path
```

Then create monit script for your application, just take look at following example of script :

You just need to create monit script in `/etc/monit.d/` like `/etc/monit.d/httpd.monit` then once reload monit service and check monit logs `tail -f /var/log/monit.log`

For Apache

```
check process apache with pidfile /usr/local/apache/logs/httpd.pid
   start program = "/etc/init.d/httpd start" with timeout 60 seconds
   stop program  = "/etc/init.d/httpd stop" 
   if cpu > 60% for 2 cycles then alert
   if cpu > 80% for 5 cycles then restart
   if totalmem > 200.0 MB for 5 cycles then restart
   if children > 250 then restart
   if loadavg(5min) greater than 10 for 8 cycles then stop
   if failed host www.tildeslash.com port 80 protocol http
      and request "/monit/doc/next.php"
      then restart
   if failed port 443 type tcpssl protocol http
      with timeout 15 seconds
      then restart
   if 3 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
   depends on apache_bin
   group server
```

For Safesquid Proxy

```
# Check if the safesquid process is running by monitoring the PID recorded in /opt/safesquid/safesquid/run/safesquid.pid
check process safesquid with pidfile /opt/safesquid/safesquid/run/safesquid.pid
group root
start program = "/etc/init.d/safesquid start"
stop program = "/etc/init.d/safesquid stop"
mode active
# If safesquid process is active it must be updating the performance log at
# /opt/safesquid/safesquid/logs/performance/performance.log every 2 seconds.
# If the file is more than 3 seconds old we definitely have a problem

check file "safesquid-PERFORMANCELOG" with path /opt/safesquid/safesquid/logs/performance/performance.log
  if timestamp > 3 SECOND then alert
```

Comment: Could you add a simple example? I've used nagios and cacti in the past and would be curious to see this as well. Is it a lot of setup or is it simple?

Comment: it's Simple , we could write own monit script, wait I will update some example

Comment: @Rahul Patil Thanks... I need a simple solution(a shell script) such that it monitors a service. My application is not that much complex , a simple application. if we provide availability stats user will easily get to know when and why service is down.

Comment: @Ram it's not complex, it's simple just install and place that script, if you need any help just ping at loginrahul90@gmail.com, I will help you on the same

Answer (score 1):

If you know the pid of the service you want monitored, I wrote this a while back for tracking resource usage of specific things on a server:

http://cognitivedissonance.ca/cogware/plog

It is completely stable, very low profile, and fairly simple to use.  It reports a slightly more detailed version of what you might see in top, but at a lower frequency and reports to a log file.  So, e.g., you could set it up to check the process every minute or five minutes -- which probably won't give you many clues as to the cause, but it will give you a window for when it stopped.

Comment: is it free for commercial use ???

Comment: @Ram : Yes.  The terms of the license (GPL, in the package) are mostly about *redistribution* or re-purposing code.

Answer (score 1):

In comments, you mentioned that you're trying to monitor a JBoss web server.

You've asked how to monitor your **service**, not your process.  It doesn't matter if JBoss is still running, if the process has wedged and isn't answering queries anymore.  You want to know if the *service is not working*, not just if the process dies.

If you don't want to run a large-scale service monitoring package like [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) or [Icinga](https://www.icinga.org/) or [Zabbix](https://www.zabbix.org) or [OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/) or [Shinken](http://www.shinken-monitoring.org/) or [Zenoss](http://www.zenoss.com/), you can always punt using something like `curl` or `wget`.

Create a script, let's call it `/root/bin/check_web`, and run it in a crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * /root/bin/check_web http://www.example.com myaddress@example.net
```

The script could look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 !~ ^https?://[a-z][a-z.]+ ]]; then
  echo "ERROR: that doesn't look like a URL ($1)" >&2
  exit 1
elif [[ $2 !~ .+@[a-z0-9.-]+ ]]; then
  echo "ERROR: that doesn't look like an email address ($2)" >&2
  exit 1
fi

flag="/tmp/m-${1//[^[:alnum:]:.-]/_}"

wget -O /dev/null -q "$1"
result=$?

if [[ $result -eq 0 ]]; then
  if [ -f "$flag" ]; then
    date | Mail -s "Clear: $1" "$2"
    rm -f "$flag"
  fi
else
  if [ ! -f "$flag" ]; then
    echo "error: $?" | Mail -s "OFFLINE: $1" "$2"
    touch "$flag"
  fi
fi
```

The nest of `if`s helps to reduce your email noise if a problem occurs.  You don't need to be distracted with another notice every 5 minutes while you're working on fixing the problem.  But it IS nice to get a notice that things have returned, in case the problem occurs from a spontaneous reboot or transient network outage.

With a slightly generic script like this, you can monitor multiple sites, and set up multiple email recipients for notification.

Create a few more of these scripts, and perhaps add functionality to issue WARNINGs for slow responses that are different from CRITICALs when the service goes offline completely, then provide a web front end to browse and manage the status of the various hosts, and create a dedicated daemon that runs these instead of cron, and you've got Nagios.  :-)

Comment: No problems.  If you have questions about how it works, please ask.  More important than *having the script* is *understanding the script*.  That way, you can customize it, or use it as an example for other scripts you may need to write.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered running Nagios?

Comment: Nagios is big application. I just want to monitor the availability of the service.